# Are there semantically identical alternatives for getaddrinfo on Win8 Metro?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am trying to port an existing, large-scale, multi-platform library to Win8 Metro, but got blocked by some removed APIs. Browsing the documentation and looking into some code samples did not help, I still cannot find a simple, reliable alternative for the missing GetAddrInfoW and getaddrinfo functions. Can anyone tell, what the proposed alternative is for these removed functions? AM I just overlooking something in the docs? Thank You, 
György

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that those functions really do not exist anymore? The [winsock docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically mention that GetAddrInfoW was actually extended in Windows 8 Consumer Preview, and not removed.

Quote: "On Windows 8 Consumer Preview and Windows Server 8 Beta, the GetAddrInfoW function provides support for IRI or Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) parsing applied to the name passed in the pNodeName parameter. Winsock performs Punycode/IDN encoding and conversion. This behavior can be disabled using the AI_DISABLE_IDN_ENCODING flag discussed below."

Edit: Looking at it again it says at the top of the document that it only applies to desktop applications. For Metro Apps winsock2 seems to be unavailable and without an equivalent alternative for those two functions. At least i couldn't find one.

Comment: Thank You Till. The function works on Win8, but only for the desktop environment. My question is about Metro Style targets. (The help page is stamped with: "Applies to: desktop apps only". And the declaration is #ifdef-ed away in the headers for Metro targets - that is really bad news to me.)

Comment: @fairlane73: I saw that after looking at it again as you can see in my edit. Sorry, that i couldn't help. I was expecting problems like this to surface with Metro. In the end you might have to bite the bullet and convert your app to use what is available in the Windows.Networking namespace.

Comment: Converting applications is definitely not an option here. We are talking about a base lib used by dozens of applications, running on several OS-es. Thank You anyway.